# How to use regexp get url pattern in golang?

Tags: regex, http, go, url-routing

How to use regular expression matching URL, which does decide to use the corresponding function processing

```
package main

import(
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
)

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/pattern", resolve)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func resolve(w http.ResponseWriter, r * http.Request) {
  fmt.Println(r.URL.Host)
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`http.HandleFunc()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandleFunc) can not be used to register a pattern to match a regular expression. In short, the pattern specified at `HandleFunc()` can match a fixed, rooted path (like `/favico.ico`) or rooted subtrees (like `/images/`), longer patterns take precedence over shorter ones. You can find more details at the doc of the [`ServeMux`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) type.

What you can do is register your handler to a rooted subtree which may be  everything with the `/` pattern, and inside your handler you can do further regexp matching and routing.

For example:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", route) // Match everything
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

var rNum = regexp.MustCompile(`\d`)  // Has digit(s)
var rAbc = regexp.MustCompile(`abc`) // Contains "abc"

func route(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch {
    case rNum.MatchString(r.URL.Path):
        digits(w, r)
    case rAbc.MatchString(r.URL.Path):
        abc(w, r)
    default:
        w.Write([]byte("Unknown Pattern"))
    }
}

func digits(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Has digits"))
}

func abc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Has abc"))
}
```

Or use an external library like Gorilla MUX.

Comment: Why to use `ServeMux` without using it's functionality? I think it is more straight forward to write your own [`HandlerFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#HandlerFunc).

Comment: @ceving I'm not sure I understand your question / concerns.

Answer (score 4):

I use [github.com/gorilla/mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) package. So router looks like:

```
func main() {

    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/{name:pattern}", handle)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

where `{name:pattern}` could be simply `{slug}` (without pattern) or `{id:[0-9]+}` or combination of them `/{category}/{id:[0-9]+}`. And get them in handler func:

```
func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    params := mux.Vars(r)

    // for /{category}/{id:[0-9]+} pattern
    category := params["category"]
    id := params["id"]
}
```

run it and try `curl http://localhost:8080/whatever/1`

Answer (score 1):

Golang doesn't have built-in *regex* support for URL matching. And it's somewhat complicated to implement from scratch.

Maybe using a *framework* would be a better choice, such as [beego](https://github.com/astaxie/beego) or [martin](https://github.com/go-martini/martini#routing), etc.