# Preserve structs data for using it later

Tags: regex, go

I'm learning golang - coding small web blog, and writing router(I know there are available few - gorilla mux, martini, etc).

I have simple struct

```
type Routes struct {    
    method string
    pattern string
    handler Handler
}
```

and some regex matchers. But i can't understand how do i keep all routes that i will define in one place. Is using slice of structs good idea(like
`[]Routes`) to keep them all together?

P.S. This is meant for personal understanding of how it all works together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really well defined. You told us you want to implement routing functionality based on regular expressions, but you haven't told us what kind of tasks you want to achieve which greatly influence the optimal or best data structure to be used.

You already mentioned you know about a lot of other implementations which are open source, maybe you should check their sources.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30474723/1705598) might also be a help to you which shows a simple implementation of a basic implementation how to do routing functionality using regular expressions.

If you just want to be able to register regular expressions which if matched by the request path and then forward the serving to a [`Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler), yes, storing the "rules" in a `[]Routes` is a viable and simple option.

Things to keep in mind:

- I would definitely compile the regexp in advance and store the result and not compile them each time which is an awful waste of resources. So your `Routes` struct should contain a field of type [`*regexp.Regexp`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp) instead of the pattern (you can keep the `string` pattern too e.g. for debugging purposes).
- If your `Routes` struct grows bigger, I would consider storing pointers in the slice and not struct values, e.g. `[]*Routes` because each time when you loop over them (e.g. in each request to see which matches) or whenever you create a local variable from one of the `Routes`, a copy is made from the values. Copying large struct is inefficient compared to copying a pointer which is fast.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but could you explain a little more about compiling regexp? Wha do you mean by compile regexp?

Comment: @Avdept If you have a regexp in Go as a `string`, if you want to check if the regexp matches another `string`, you can do that for example with the [`Regexp.MatchString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.MatchString) method. `Regexp` is a compiled (analyzed) version of a `string` regular expression. You can compile a regexp `string` and acquire a `Regexp` value with the [`regexp.Compile()`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Compile) or [`regexp.MustCompile()`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#MustCompile) functions for example.