# golang http: how to route requests to handlers

Tags: http, go

I'm newbie on Golang and have a simple question about building a web server.

Saying that my web server has users so the users can change their names and their passwords. Here is how I design the URLs:

```
/users/Test         GET
/users/Test/rename       POST   newname=Test2
/users/Test/newpassword  POST   newpassword=PWD
```

The first line is to show the information of the user named `Test`. The second and the third is to rename and to reset password.

So I'm thinking that I need to use some regular expression to match the HTTP requests, things like `http.HandleFunc("/users/{\w}+", controller.UsersHandler)`.

However, it doesn't seem that Golang supports such a thing. So does it mean that I have to change my design? For example, to show the information of the user `Test`, I have to do `/users   GET   name=Test`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to run pattern matching on r.URL.Path, using the regex package (in your case you may need it on POST) [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474313/how-to-use-regexp-get-url-pattern-in-golang) shows some pattern matching samples. As @Eugene suggests there are routers/http utility packages also which can help.

Here's something which can give you some ideas, in case you don't want to use other packages:

In main:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", multiplexer)
...
func multiplexer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method {
    case "GET":
        getHandler(w, r)
    case "POST":
        postHandler(w, r)
    }
}

func getHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    //Match r.URL.path here as required using switch/use regex on it
}

func postHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    //Regex as needed on r.URL.Path 
    //and then get the values POSTed
    name := r.FormValue("newname")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately standard http router not to savvy. There are 2 ways:

Manually check methods, urls and extract usernames.

Use routers from other packages like 
https://github.com/gorilla/mux

gorilla mix, echo gin-gonic etc